# Creating framework in IOS that contains controllers

Tags: iphone, ios

If I create a IOS framework that will be shared between projects, can it contain things like ViewControllers?  The project will only contain resources related to that project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there other frameworks that contain view controllers?  I would say certainly so.

The bigger question would be "can it contain the resources I want to use with those view controllers?"

It is possible, but it is a pain in the neck.  [Here is some reference](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/iPhone_Framework_Support.20081202.html) on how to do so.

Also the [FaceBook developer kit](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/concepts/ios-build-distribute-promote/) is a good example of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your framework can have view controllers.